# A "uniform continuity" type condition on an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Let $K: I\times I\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar kernel such that: $s \rightarrow K(t, s)$  is integrable and $t \rightarrow K(t, s)$ is continuous.

My goal is to prove that (*if it's true*):

\begin{array}{l}
\text { For each } \epsilon>0 \text { , there exists } \delta>0 \text { such that, for any } t_{1}, t_{2} \in I, \text { if }\left|t_{1}-t_{2}\right|<\delta \text { then }\\
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} K(t_2,s) d s< \epsilon
\end{array}

**Edit (for clarification)**: I'm currently reading this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-02/S0002-9939-96-03154-1/S0002-9939-96-03154-1.pdf) (and working on a similar one). The main goal is to study the Hammerstein integral equation (in $\mathcal{C}(I,E))$:

$$x(t) = \int_{0}^{t} K(t,s)f\big(s,x(s)\big)ds,\quad t\in I;$$

where $I=[0,1]$,  $K $ is a scalar kernel, $E$  a Banach space and $f:I \times E \rightarrow E$ is a given function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Let for example $I=[0,1]$, and $K(t,s)= (1/[1-t])$ for s in $I$, and 0<t<1, and $K(t,s)=0$ if $t=1$. Then the integrability condition holds, but for 0<x,y<1, $\int_x^y K(y,s)ds= [y-x]/[1-y]$, which cannot be made uniformly small as y gets close to 1 by simply bounding y-x. If on the other hand for example $K$ were additionally continuous (hence also bounded if $I$ is compact) the result would hold. $\int_x^y K(y,s)ds \le M(y-x),$ where $M$ is the upper bound of K.

Comment: Great, what if we add that $K$ is **continuous on $t$** (Something like Carathéodory condition), can we get the same result?